# Azure Event Hub Failed Request

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hub. Our log events go to our Event Hub. I have set up alerting for Failed Request. I keep getting Failed Request. 
How do I drill more into this? How do I know what is causing this issue? Azure Portal just gives me a counter which is not helpful. I enabled Diagnostics Log (which is connected to my storage account) but again this logs is a json and shows me failreq count and srvbsy count without details.

So questions:

1. How do I know what is going on or causing these Failed Request?
2. What can I do to enable more info.
3. How can I retry this failed request? Can I move these failed request to some Q to retry?

Update (to address Mikhail's question): 
This is the metric which Azure Provides to monitor the Event Hub. Unfortunately, there is not much help or info on what this failure is. This is what they provide:

FAILREQ: Failed Requests : Count : Total : Total failed requests for a namespace :No Dimensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics

Comment: Requests to what?

Comment: @Mikhail updated my question. This is failed request to namespace. they dont have enough information.